How to avoid tempory variable create and dead when emplace_back a pair object?
I have a vector container, typename is std::pair, but i found there are many construct/deconstruct operation when add element.
Here is a demo code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A { 
  explicit A(int a) : a_(a) {
    printf("%d created at %p\n", a_, (void *)this);
  }
  A(const A &other) : a_(other.a_) { printf("%d copied\n", a_); }
  A(A &&other) : a_(other.a_) {
    printf("%d moved into %p\n", a_, (void *)this);
  }
  A &operator=(const A &other) {
    printf("%d copy assigned\n", a_);
    a_ = other.a_;
    return *this;
  }
  A &operator=(A &&other) {
    printf("%d move assigned to %p\n", a_, (void *)this);
    a_ = other.a_;
    return *this;
  }
  ~A() { printf("%d %p dead\n", a_, (void *)this); }
  int a_; 
  void show() const { printf("%d\n", a_); }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<A, A>> v;
  v.emplace_back(std::make_pair(A(1), A(2)));
  while(1);
}

g++ a.cpp -O2
./a.out

2 created at 0x7fffb413ca84
1 created at 0x7fffb413ca80
1 moved into 0x7fffb413ca88
2 moved into 0x7fffb413ca8c
1 moved into 0x1cf72c0
2 moved into 0x1cf72c4
2 0x7fffb413ca8c dead
1 0x7fffb413ca88 dead
1 0x7fffb413ca80 dead
2 0x7fffb413ca84 dead

as the output shows:
there are four temp variable was created, how to reduce it?

If you do the std::make_pair call by itself, you'll see that 8 of those 10 lines are due to the make_pair, not the emplace_back.

Why not just write
v.emplace_back(1, 2);
instead of what you currently have:
v.emplace_back(std::make_pair(A(1), A(2)));
?
Running this modified code, I get only:
1 created at 0x586bf7ac12b0
2 created at 0x586bf7ac12b4


That only works starting with C++ 17.  Prior to that, the make_pair call was required.

@TimRoberts It works with C++11. See here.

thanks, does this work for single arg consturctor only? if the construct has 2 args, how to do that?

Constructing a pair has 2 arguments. That's the advantage of emplace_back compared to push_back. It constructs in place.

@kevinh You could use piecewise_construct.
